# Node properties are not displayed correctly

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a .csv file with three columns separated by ",". The first column contains first names, the 2nd column contains the last names and the 3rd column contains values:

```
Lname,Fname,Num
Brown,Helen,3
Right,Eliza,1
Green,Helen,3
Pink,Kate,2
Yellow,Helen,3
```

and another .csv file like this:

```
central,value
cent1,10
```

I want to create nodes for Lname column and nodes for Fname column. For the rows that have the same Fname, I want to connect Lname to the corresponding Fname. For example I want to have a "Helen" node that three nodes "Brown", "Green" and "Yellow" connected to "Helen" (Also if Fname is identical, Num is identical too) I also want to connect "Fname" nodes to a "central node". This is my desired output:

[image]

I use this code:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///central.csv' AS frow
MERGE (c:center {name: frow.central})
WITH *
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///names.csv' AS srow
WITH srow.Fname AS first, srow.Lname AS last, srow.Num as num
MERGE (p:la {last: last})
MERGE (o:fi {first: first, num: num})
MERGE (c)-[r:CONTAINS {first:first}]->(o)
MERGE (o)-[rel:CONTAINS {first: first}]->(p)
RETURN count(o)
```

When I click on each `first` node in Neo4j, I expect to see `first` and `num` as its properties because of this line:

```
MERGE (o:fi {first: first, num: num})
```

but using this code, only one of the `first` nodes contains the `num` as its properties. Other `first` nodes do not show the `num` as their properties. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your `names.csv` file has an error. `Helen` appears with 2 different `Num` values: 2 and 3. This is why your query created 2 different `Helen` nodes. The file should look like this:

   ```
   Lname,Fname,Num
   Brown,Helen,3
   Right,Eliza,1
   Green,Helen,3
   Pink,Kate,2
   Yellow,Helen,3
   ```
2. Your second `WITH` clause did not specify `c`, so `c` became an unbound variable. This caused the `MERGE (c)-[:CONTAINS]->(o)` clause to create a new `c` node instead of re-using the original `c` node.

   This is a fixed version of your query:

   ```
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///central.csv' AS frow
   MERGE (c:center {name: frow.central})
   WITH c
   LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///names.csv' AS srow
   WITH c, srow.Fname AS first, srow.Lname AS last, srow.Num as num
   MERGE (p:la {last: last})
   MERGE (o:fi {first: first, num: num})
   MERGE (c)-[:CONTAINS]->(o)
   MERGE (o)-[:CONTAINS]->(p)
   RETURN count(o)
   ```

   *Note: I also removed the `{first:first}` property settings from the `CONTAINS` relationships, as it is not recommendeded to store redundant information in the DB. One of the end nodes of that relationship is always going to have the first name anyway. In fact, it would also be best practice to use different relationship types (e.g., `CONTAINS` and `HAS_LAST_NAME`).*

Comment: Thanks. It was a typing mistake here, I edited the post. In my .csv file `Helen` has identical `num` values. I don't have 2 `helen` nodes. My problem is that for example when I click on the `helen` node, I can see its `num` value as its property, but when I click on `Eliza` node, its `num` value is not displayed.

Comment: I tested with my answer's data and query, and the `Eliza` node does have the `num` property. Try deleting the existing nodes and relationships and then running my query.

Comment: Are you still having the same problem?